# Values from list of python dictionaries to tab separated file

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary of various ID's I need to write to a file with the values under each key as their own row, tab separated.

In the end I want the file to look like this:

```
    user1_id1 <tab> user1_id2 <tab> user1_id3 <tab>
    user2_id2<tab>...
```

I cannot use pandas since this library is too large for the application we are using. Currently I have my results in a list of dictionaries with each element as a user and their various ID's as key value pairs within each element

```
[{id1: 230423, id2:sdfkjs}, {id1:1932, id2:sjsdf}...]
```

Is there a way to extract the values within the dictionaries within the list and then write those to a file with the id's contained in each element as their own row, tab separated?

Comment: [`csv.DictWriter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter) with [`delimiter='\t'`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.Dialect.delimiter)?

Comment: Of course there is a way to do that. What specifically are you having problems with? (please show your attempt)

Comment: @DeliriousLettuce that may work, I will look into that library. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simple example of using `csv.DictWriter`

```
>>> import csv
... 
... fieldnames = ('id1', 'id2')
... result = [
...     {'id1': 230423, 'id2': 'sdfkjs'},
...     {'id1': 1932, 'id2': 'sjsdf'}
... ]
... 
... with open('test.csv', 'w') as f:
...     writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=fieldnames, delimiter='\t')
...     writer.writeheader()
...     writer.writerows(result)
... 
>>> with open('test.csv', 'r') as f:
...     for line in f:
...         print(line.rstrip())
... 
id1 id2
230423  sdfkjs
1932    sjsdf
```

Reading it back in as dictionaries is easy as well using `csv.DictReader`

```
>>> with open('test.csv', 'r') as f:
...     reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter='\t')
...     for line in reader:
...         print(dict(line))
... 
{'id1': '230423', 'id2': 'sdfkjs'}
{'id1': '1932', 'id2': 'sjsdf'}
```